# how to display a value from json into a drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop down list that is already populated. So when a page loads it must show what value was selected previously.I get the value a user has selected from the from the database.

this is the current drop down

````
       ```  <select name="Items"  valtype="required" runat="server" id="Items"> 
                        <option value="-1">--Select--</option>  
                        <option value="Milk">Milk</option>
                        <option value="Sugar">Sugar</option>
                        <option value="Coffee">Coffee</option>
                       </select> ```
````

this is my code that i read from the db

```
function Changed(itemreturned)// pass value from db
{
  var items=$('#Items');
 //what i tried 
items.val=items.innerHTML + '<option value="' + items[0].Items + '">' + itemreturned[0].Items + '</option>';
// second try
item.val=item.options[itemreturned[0].Items];

}
```

json result

```
  itemreturned
{ 
 Items:Milk
}
```

so what i am trying to do is that since "Milk" was returned i want to display that in the item drop downbox instead of "--select--"
But i already have an option loaded for "milk" in the list so how do i match the result returned from the db and the items in the list and display that specific value.

Answer (score 1):

I belive this is how you want it:

```
function Changed(itemreturned) // pass value from db
{
  var items = $('#Items');
  items.val(itemreturned.Items);
}
```

First of with `jQuery` it's `item.val(yourvalue)` not `item.val = yourvalue`.

Second, in your code you have `item.val` and I guess `item` should have been `items` you need to take it a bit slower when you code, and use the console, so check for error, because this would have said that nothing named `item` would exist.

**Demo**

```js
function Changed(itemreturned) // pass value from db
{
  var items = $('#Items');
  items.val(itemreturned.Items);
}

var itemreturned = {
  Items: "Milk"
}

Changed(itemreturned)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="Items" valtype="required" runat="server" id="Items">
  <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
  <option value="Milk">Milk</option>
  <option value="Sugar">Sugar</option>
  <option value="Coffee">Coffee</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this code snippet will fully serve your purpose.

```js
function Changed(itemreturned) // pass value from db
{
  let selectElm = document.getElementById("Items");
  let options = selectElm.options;

  //looping over all the options and matching with your db values
  //if match is found make that the selected index.
  for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    if (options[i].text === itemreturned.Items) {
      selectElm.options.selectedIndex = options[i].index;
    }
  }
}

let itemreturned = {
  Items: "Milk"
}

Changed(itemreturned);
```

```html
<select name="Items" valtype="required" runat="server" id="Items">
  <option idx=1 value="-1">--Select--</option>
  <option idx=2 value="Milk">Milk</option>
  <option idx=3 value="Sugar">Sugar</option>
  <option idx=4 value="Coffee">Coffee</option>
</select>
```

You can change your incoming database value and check for match accordingly.If no match found it will show --Select-- by default.
 [Here's js fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/4fdqL09t/2/)

Feel free to ask if you have any questions about this.